# Finding the intersecting points of two strictly monotonic increasing functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, roots, monotone-functions

I need to prove this:
Let $f$ be a strictly monotonic continuous real-valued function defined on $[a,b]$ such that $f(a)<a$ and $f(b)>b$, then $\exists$ exactly one c $\in$ $(a,b)$ such that $f(c)=c$

**My attempt**

I could figure out from the given data that $f$ is strictly increasing. I tried to construct a new function:

> $g(x)=f(x)-x$

and I got $g(a)<0$  and  $g(b)>0$. I now know for sure that there exits *at least* one such c $\in$ $(a,b)$ such that $f(c)=c$. But how do I conclude there is exactly one such $c$?

Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
I may have chosen the wrong one but there are other options to choose from:

1. $\exists$ exactly one c $\in$ $(a,b)$ such that $f(c)=c$
2. $\exists$ $c_1, c_2$ $\in$ $(a,b)$ such that $f(c_1)=c_1$ and $f(c_2)=c_2$
3. $\exists$ no such c $\in$ $(a,b)$ such that $f(c)=c$
4. $\exists$ infinitely many such c $\in$ $(a,b)$ such that $f(c)=c$

Comment: What about $f(x)=x^3$ on $[-2,2]$?

Comment: @DavidMitra You are right, I am a bit confused with the options.

Comment: None of your options need hold.

Comment: @DavidMitra I do feel the same. This is a question from IIIT JAM 2016 paper and the official answer key says option 1. I guess they made a mistake, though its really rare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOT TRUE.

Take
$$
f(x)=x+\frac{1}{2}\sin x.
$$
Then $f'(x)>0$ and $f(x)=x$, whenever $x=k\pi$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and also sorry as I got late to type the options which should have been taken into consideration. Kindly have a look at my edit.